# Everything in the form disappeared

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I have created an Windows Form. I have worked very hard on it. I inserted a bunifu button and the deleted it via Form.Designer.cs. The form and it's border still appears (I set border to none) !(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yeqrq.jpg)
It doesn't work at all.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. You need to provide all the details and 
mention the issue clearly. Please refer the
[ask] link for more detail and update your question accordingly. Based on the current information it is very hard to help you.

Comment: Have you write `Form1.Show();`?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a ton of info here. If the project is still open you could try to ctrl-Z your way back. Hopefully you are using some sort of version control. If so you could utilize that. Otherwise I believe we will need to see more code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem that happens to me, quite often. But it depends on the code. So, first of all, post your code so we can see it and tell what is the problem. Now, by guessing, possible solutions:

- Check your design code. See if you removed anything by accident. If yes try doing it the right way.
- Try cleaning and rebuilding your project. Sometimes files can get corrupted and that can help.
- Try pressing Ctrl+Z to undo and see if it does something. As @alphamalle said, you should have been using a kind of version control(git, etc.) so you could easily go back to your previous revision.

If all of these don't work, then sadly we can't tell. Please post your code, because the project could have been permanently deleted. Good lesson to use version control.